# sorting table doesnt work how its supposed to be

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

I created a table that is getting sorted by clicking on the headers. But the sorting doesnt work well. Look at the picture for an example (its sorted ascending) [how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b9LK.png)

my js code:

```
function sortTable(n) {
  var table,
    rows,
    switching,
    i,
    x,
    y,
    shouldSwitch,
    dir,
    switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  dir = "asc";
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) { //Change i=0 if you have the header th a separate table.
      shouldSwitch = false;
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      switchcount++;
    } else {
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }}}}
```

I guess you already know my question.
Q: how can i make sure its getting correctly sorted? Do i really have to fill the Values up with '0's before the real value or is there a better way?

Comment: it looks like it is sorted by string instead of sort by number, but without your code not much I can do.

Comment: it is saved as string (varchar), because it could be a mix of numbers and text

Comment: Code would definitely help. How do you sort?

Comment: https://codepen.io/andrese52/pen/ZJENqp i used this example. The JS Code is exactly the same. But it should be sorting by string in 7 of 8 cases (table has 8 columns, 7 of them are with text) --edited

Comment: _"Nearly the same"_... then please share *actual* code, because any differences might matter.

Comment: How is the function triggered? Currently, it seems you could decide based on the parameter `n` whether you should try and parse the value as a number or not.

Comment: its triggered through an onclick event in <tr><th onlick="sometext(0)"></th></tr> but the parameter n should be used for deciding, which header got clicked. Thats what i thought

Comment: So, if `n` equals a specific number, you could try and run `parseInt` on the contents. Alternatively, you could add a second boolean parameter to the function, something like `sortNumeric` which you'd use for this purpose (this solution seems cleaner).

Comment: thank you @El_Vanja. I´ll try it with sortNumeric when i have some free time, that looks like a good hint! I´ts for a project at work and i can only work on it when i have nothing else to do and right now i have too much to do to try it.